# Where is tasklist_lock defined in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

The [`linux/shed.h`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.2.2/include/linux/sched.h#L257) contains the following forward declaration:

```
extern rwlock_t tasklist_lock;
```

But where is `tasklist_lock` defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tasklist_lock` is references in `sched.h`, and defined in `fork.c`

I use "gid" as a tool to spelunk through the kernel source.  I simply:

1) Install idutils

2) Run "`mkid`" (to generate a searchable index) from the root of my kernel source

3) run "`gid MYVARIABLE | less`" any time I want to look something up

"idutils" is freely available on most Linux distros, and on the Internet.

Here's the documentation:

http://www.gnu.org/software/idutils/manual/idutils.html

Comment: LXR and ctags are more-known indexers.